# Woman travels back to past and pretends to predict future

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A short story about a woman who gets paid for predicting future which she already knows because she time traveled to the past.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  How (and why) did she travel to the past?  What is the setting of the story?

Comment: This is a fairly common trope. Can you provide any more details? Book/magazine/online, when you read it, male or female author, what sort of predictions did she make (e.g. stock market, global events, sports results), ....  Anything at all you remember will help someone else ID it.